# What type of 4-pin 1mm-pitch clippy connector is this?

Tags: identification, cables

I have recently bought a [lidar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075V5TZRY) sensor with a peculiar cable type. I cannot identify it, but it has some interesting characteristics. It has a pitch of 1mm, and each pin has at most a 0.5mm width. The cable itself is for UART, but I'm not sure if the connector was made for it.

Here is a close up of the male end.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search, The cable type appears to be a **GH1.25-4P** connector
[image]

Comment: This does not seem to match the connector in your previous picture at all. Not the same type of attachment, not the same pitch, not the same edges...

Comment: @jcaron I'll double check when i get home

Comment: It does seems to be a JST-GH connector indeed (which has 1.25 mm pitch, not 1 mm), but your picture here does not seem to match that connector.